# Disabling a button on a webpage

Tags: vb.net

I have a web site written in MS Studio VB 2008. At the start of the subroutine that handles the Click event of a button I disable the button but it's not working. It only disables AFTER the subroutine runs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try to disable on client side using `onclientclick` event

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the form requires a postback. Set the autopostback property to true, or this could be handled dynamically with javascript.

```
Button1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Where do I set the autopostback property? I don't see it in the properties list. Thanx

Comment: I added autopostback="True" to the form definition but it still didn't work --> <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data"  autopostback="True">

Comment: Add the code within the answer and perform this on the click event and it should be disabled if your postback is set

Comment: I did but it only got disabled AFTER the subroutine finished

Comment: Sorry could you provide some code so I can take a look.Thanks

Comment: Protected Sub SubmitApplications_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitApplications.Click

        'Dim iConfirmation As MsgBoxResult

        SubmitApplications.Enabled = False

Comment: Here's the form definition: <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data"  
    autopostback="True" method="post">

Comment: Try adding Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx") before the subroutine? Set some kind of a flag so it knows its a redirect, and set the button to enabled false within the page load. Not sure if it will work but worth a try

Comment: OK Post full relevant code so i can mimic whats going on, as its very hard to do with small snippets.

Comment: This worked: <asp:Button ID="SubmitApplications" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="SubmitApplications_Click" Text="Submit Applications"  
            OnClientClick="this.disabled = true;" 
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" Height="40px" Width="319px" />